# Convert Ubuntu installation to Kylin

Tags: upgrade, convert, chinese, kylin

How can I convert my existing Ubuntu installation into Ubuntu Kylin?

Will just changing the repositories do the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is sufficient to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntukylin-desktop
```

The metapackage `ubuntukylin-desktop` provides all the standard apps for Kylin desktop, although in the past releases there were a few packages missing ( for instance, on my 16.04 system `wechat` webapp was only in the installation from an actual iso images, and WPS office had to be  installed manually )

Comment: Have tried it and IT WORKED just perfect. Thanks Serg.

Comment: Then please accept this answer. Also, it is better to keep using only one DE (Desktop Environment) Otherwise they might make conflict. If you know you wont use Ubuntu (Unity) remove it and just keep using kylin